How can I create middle points starting from an imported mesh?
I need to create a wire path starting from a tube coming from a CAD system.
When I'm importing the file, Blender create a mesh with different points in order to re-create the original faces.
My goal in reality is the described path. So I'm trying to understand if it's possible to recover the path of a tube (or wire) finding the middle point passing in the tube path.
I know that is not so difficult to copy the path and re-make it, but every day I will make it several times. My work is to make wires simulations on electrical motors. It is important to have the path with driving point, but it takes a lot of time making from zero. So I try to start from the CAD model.

I hope this is clear.
Many thanks for your help.

Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258701/how-to-convert-or-merge-a-tube-into-a-single-line-curve and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259723/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-collapse-all-edge-rings-or-scale-a-tube-thickness

Many thanks. It is exactly what I was looking for.
